# Django .exclude() returns empty queryset

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a problem with `.exclude()` when making a QuerySet.

My models involved are:

Profession

```
class Profession(models.Model):
    profession_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    equipment = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment, blank=True)
    ability = models.ManyToManyField(Ability, blank=True)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True)
    skill_advanced = models.ManyToManyField(SkillAdvanced, blank=True)
```

Ability

```
class Ability(models.Model):
    ability_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
```

When I create QuerySet with:

```
self.prof_abilities = Profession.objects.filter(profession_name="Acolyte").values('ability')
```

I get:

```
<QuerySet [{'ability': 2}, {'ability': 69}, {'ability': 81}, {'ability': 86}, {'ability': 23}]>
```

But I would like to exclude some values, so I use this instead:

```
self.prof_abilities = Profession.objects.filter(profession_name="Acolyte").exclude(ability__in=[2, 23, 81, 86]).values('ability')
```

But the outcome is an empty QuerySet:
`<QuerySet []>`.
I've tried various tweeks like `.exclude(ability__id__in=[2, 23, 81, 86])` or `.exclude(ability__ability_name__in=['Foo name', 'Bar name']` but with no success.

I'm new to Django so if this is something obvious, I would also appreciate some pointers
where to read more on my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your queryset is for the `Profession` model, hence when you write `queryset.exclude(ability__in=<list_of_abilities>)` you get a queryset where you exclude `Profession` (Not `Ability`) instances where the ability is in the given list, i.e. if any of the `Ability` related to a `Profession` is in that list that profession would be excluded. Instead if you get the `Profession` object first and then filter on the relation manager you will get your expected result:

```py
queryset = Profession.objects.filter(profession_name="Acolyte")

for profession in queryset:
    print(profession.ability.exclude(id__in=[2, 23, 81, 86]))
```

Comment: Your explanation gave me a sense of direction and what I'm doing wrong. But I don't quite understand your implementation of looping. I would like to get a queryset that can be passed to view,. Basically I want a SQL equivalent of SELECT ability FROM Profession WHERE profession_name='Acolyte' and ability NOT IN [2, 23, 81, 86]

Comment: @korni The SQL you suggest is wrong for your models, a `ManyToManyField` creates an intermediate / through model (table) with foreign keys to both of the related models (i.e. if you want to filter on ability there you would need a join). Also in case `profession_name` is supposed to be unique (ideally should be if you identify objects by that) you can simply write `profession = Profession.objects.get(profession_name="Acolyte")` and then `profession.ability.exclude(id__in=[2, 23, 81, 86])`. That loop is just there to demonstrate the concept without assuming things.

Comment: Thank you very much I'm marking it as an answer. So my main mistake was excluding professions that have those ID's, trying to make a bad query for a ManyToManyField work and finally it could all work fine if I used `.get` instead of `.filter` and then `.exclude` to get rid of what I don't need... well glad that you could clarify it for me :D

Answer (score 2):

Since `Ability` is a `manyToManyField`, the each `profession.ability` object will have `django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager` and not the direct list of ability objects. So if you want to get All professions that excludes ability with specific ids you can try changing your query from

```
self.prof_abilities = Profession.objects.filter(profession_name="Acolyte").exclude(ability__in=[2, 23, 81, 86]).values('ability')
```

to

```
self.prof_abilities = Profession.objects.filter(profession_name="Acolyte").exclude(ability__in=Ability.objects.filter(id__in=[2, 23, 81, 86])).values('ability')
```

`filter` and `exclude` behaves differently with respect to `multi-valued relationships`.

Although didn't find a link for valid explanation for my answer, here is a link from documentation discussing something related

Scroll down to `note` part of this section link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: maybe I was not clear about what I want to achieve, but I didn't want to exclude professions, rather I wanted to get a specific profession 'Acolyte' that has many abilities without the ones that I pointed in `.exclude([2, ...])` but thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, your filter that fetch specific profession 'Acolyte' remains same, the 'exclude' part that i specified will serve your requirement of skipping the abilitiy_ids you pass in the list without a for loop or any kind of iteration